# getting Segmentation fault on PcapNgFileReaderDevice::close()

Tags: pcapplusplus

**#0  0x000000000049344c in light_pcapng_close ()
#1  0x0000000000480cbe in pcpp::PcapNgFileReaderDevice::close() ()
**

i am getting this error on my setup.
how can i resolve this error .

Comment: This might be related to the pcapng file you're trying to open, it's very hard to debug without further information